# A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'. [Flutter,Android Studio]

Tags: flutter, dependencies, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies, tflite

I tried to use the tflite package to create a live object detection app, but it seems that after I installed both the packages: ***tflite*** and ***camera***, and also wrote the detection code it didn't seem to run.

Packages : Tflite: https://pub.dev/packages/tflite Camera: https://pub.dev/packages/camera

The error I faced: `A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'.`

`> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

The Entire Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\dlprw\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle' line: 36

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+] on object of type org.grad
le.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

My Pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: captureit
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.5 <4.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  gallery_saver: ^2.3.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+1
  loading_animation_widget: ^1.2.0+4
  path_provider: ^2.0.14
  tflite: ^1.1.2
  camera: ^0.10.3
  debounce_throttle: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:


  uses-material-design: true
```

My *android/app/build.gradle* file :

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.captureit"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.captureit"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:+'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
}
```

My *android/build.gradle* file :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried adding these dependencies in `android/app/build.gradle`, not `android/build.gradle`.

I also tried:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    //Don't put dependencies here.
  }
}

dependencies {
 //Put them here
}
```